# How to pass command line arguments to my dockerized python app

Tags: docker

I have a simple docker file which I am using to containerize my python app. The app actually takes file paths as command line arguments. It is my first time using Docker and I am wondering how I can achieve this:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install gcc g++
# Install numpy, pandas, scipy and scikit
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt
RUN python setup.py install

ENTRYPOINT python -m myapp.testapp
```

Please note that the python app is run from the from the module with the `-m` flag.

This builds the image completely fine. I can also run it using:

```
docker run -ti myimg
```

However, I cannot pass any command line arguments to it. For example, my app prints some help options with the -h option.

However, running docker as:

```
docker run -ti myimg -h
```

does not do anything. So, the command line option are not being passed.

Additionally, I was wondering what the best way to actually pass file handles from the host computer to docker. So, for example, the application takes path to a file as an input and the file would usually reside on the host computer. Is there a way for my containerized app to be able to access that?

Comment: I would go with the default entrypoint (usually `/bin/sh -c` if not mistaken) and would have gone with `docker run -ti myimg python -m myapp.testapp -h`. Could you try if it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the `CMD` instruction along with `ENTRYPOINT`(in exec form)

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "-m", "myapp.testapp"]
CMD [""]
```

Make sure whatever default value you are passing to CMD, (`""` in the above snippet), it is ignored by your main command

When you do, `docker run -ti myimg`,
the command will be executed as `python -m myapp.testapp ''`

When you do, `docker run -ti mying -h`,
the command will be executed as `python -m myapp.testapp -h`

Note:
exec form: `ENTRYPOINT ["command", "parameter1", "parameter2"]`
shell form: `ENTRYPOINT command parameter1 parameter2`

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I had tried this before but did not use the exec form. Thanks again!